# display alert once per visit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working how to display alert message once if the user visits site first time. The message should be visible on every page until close button is pressed. I put the code in _Layout.cshtml, but it is not working I wonted to.

Can you point my mistake?

```
@if(Session["Alert"] != "Confirmed")
{
    <div id="myAlert" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myAlert").on('closed.bs.alert', function () {
        sessionStorage.Alert = "Confirmed";
    });
});
</script>
```

The alert is displayed every time the site/page is reloaded. It looks as if the script is not executed when alert close button is pressed. What is more the session["Alert"] is not set.

Comment: You said it's not working like you wanted it to. Describe **how** it doesn't work like you want it to.

Comment: I think it's != in your first line of code which should be !==

Comment: I think using cookies are more appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sessionStorage` and server side `Session` are not the same thing! You can't set values to `sessionStorage` and expect to get it from server side `Session`. So you have two choices:

**1. Use server side `Session`**

Change your javascript code to send an ajax request to a mvc action, then set `Session["Alert"]` to "Confirmed" there.

**2. Use `sessionStorage`**

Instead of using `@if(Session["Alert"] != "Confirmed")`, you check `sessionStorage` on document ready to decide whether to show the alert.

The 2nd one requires minimum code to change. The following code will work :

```
<div id="myAlert" style="display:none" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // If not 'Confirmed', show #myAlert
            if (sessionStorage.Alert !== 'Confirmed') {
                $('#myAlert').show();
            }
        });

        $('#myAlert .close').click(function () {
            // Set 'Alert' to 'Confirmed' when user click the close button
            sessionStorage.Alert = "Confirmed";
            $(this).closest('#myAlert').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind Page_Load sub, I set my session variable:

```
    If IsNothing(Session("visit")) Then
        Session("visit") = "no"
    Else
        Session("visit") = "yes"
    End If
```

In the body tag, I put an onload event:

onload="showAlert();"

Then I added this small javascript function:

```
    function showAlert() {

        var visit = '<%= Session("visit")%>';
        if (visit == 'no') {
            document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'block';
        }            
    }
```

The first time a visitor hits my landing page, they see the welcome alert I have saved in a div with id='id01'. The next time during this visit that they hit the landing page, the session is changed to yes on page load and they don't see the alert again.